# How do I calculate the takeoff for a 45 degree elbow joint?

Tags: plumbing

I'm trying to install a 45° elbow joint in PVC. I've found several suggestions online, but frankly, they are incomprehensible to me and seem contradictory of one another:

- http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_fiqure_takeoff_for_45_degree_elbow
- http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_take_off_measurements_for_45_degree_pipe_fittings
- http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_calculate_a_45_degree_elbow_center

Is there a straightforward way to calculate the takeoff?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the particular fitting being used?

Comment: Such ratio calculations may give you an approximately useful value, but there are variations between manufacturers, and of course fittings. I wouldn't trust anything if real accuracy is needed except actually measuring or using the manufacturer's dimension tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a definition of **"take off"**:
The length of pipe to be removed (taken off) such that a pipe and a fitting make a specific length.  The term is a concept shorthand used by pipefitters and plumbers.  This is not the same as a material takeoff, which is a list of all materials needed for a project.

Take-offs in general are specific to pipe construction (PVC, copper, etc.) and is a function of diameter.

As suggested by bcworkz, tables for a given diameter and style of pipe are the best method for an accurate measurement.

The formula (listed in your link) .625 x pipe size (don't use the 25.4 factor, unless you are using millimeters) should give you a ballpark for a 45 fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel. The unit is (inch) according to the unit of pipe diameter (D)and any pipe diameter is applicable in formulas. (The Picture is only geometrical prove to have a better perspective).
See below picture with more details.
[image: 45 DEG-LR & SR TYP- T.O Calculation]

Comment: Hi, Jalal. Thanks for the improvements, but we prefer that you edit an answer to improve it, rather than creating a new, improved answer. I've marked your other answer as a duplicate. (And, I condensed the image a bit.)